# Emulate Apple Pay in an nfc Tag

Tags: nfc, payment, applepay

i'm trying to emulate apple pay on a nfc tag to make payments through it. The tag is an NTAG213 and I would like to understand if it is possible to do it and how. I tried downloading nfctools but there are no direct functions that allow you to configure the payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, an NTAG213 is a Type 2 NFC Tag where as NFC payments use ISO 7816 (as used by NFC Type 4 Tags) to communicate.

Even if you tried with a commercially available NFC Type 4 Tag then you won't be able to configure it operate the Application protocols needed for payment.